# Google Drive API Java, Authentication works for first time only

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client, google-oauth

I use following code to upload file to google drive, it is used for java based web application. Everything works fine except authentication.

The main problem with the code is that it just ask once for authentication and later on when I run the project, it never ask for authentication.

I want authentication for each and every request made by client.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package myapp.util;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.InputStreamContent;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;

import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.*;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

public class GDrive {

    /**
     * Application name.
     */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME
            = "Drive API Java Quickstart";

    /**
     * Directory to store user credentials for this application.
     */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/drive-java-quickstart.json");

    /**
     * Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}.
     */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /**
     * Global instance of the JSON factory.
     */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY
            = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /**
     * Global instance of the HTTP transport.
     */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     *
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials at
     * ~/.credentials/drive-java-quickstart
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES
            = Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE);

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     *
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
        String basePath = servletContext.getRealPath("");
        basePath = URLDecoder.decode(basePath, "UTF-8");
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(
                new java.io.File(basePath + "/resources/client_secret.json"));
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets
                = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow
                = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .setApprovalPrompt("auto")
                .build();

       GoogleCredential credential  = new GoogleCredential();
        System.out.println(
                "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Drive client service.
     *
     * @return an authorized Drive client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Drive getDriveService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        System.out.println("getAccessToken" + credential.getAccessToken());

        System.out.println("setAccessToken" + credential.getAccessToken());
        System.out.println("setExpiresInSeconds" + credential.getExpiresInSeconds());

        System.out.println("setRefreshToken" + credential.getRefreshToken());
        return new Drive.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    public boolean uploadToDrive(String filePathUrl, String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException, Exception {
        Drive service = GDrive.getDriveService();
        boolean status = false;
        // TODO code application logic here
        java.io.File mediaFile = new java.io.File(filePathUrl);
        com.google.api.services.drive.model.File fileMetadata = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
        fileMetadata.setName(fileName);
        InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("application/octet-stream", new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(mediaFile)));
        mediaContent.setLength(mediaFile.length());

        HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        Drive.Files.Create request = service.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent);
        request.getMediaHttpUploader().setProgressListener(new CustomProgressListener());
        request.execute();
        status = true;
        return status;
    }

}

class CustomProgressListener implements MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener {

    public void progressChanged(MediaHttpUploader uploader) throws IOException {
        switch (uploader.getUploadState()) {
            case INITIATION_STARTED:
                System.out.println("Initiation has started!");
                break;
            case INITIATION_COMPLETE:
                System.out.println("Initiation is complete!");
                break;
            case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
                System.out.println(uploader.getProgress());
                break;
            case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
                System.out.println("Upload is complete!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did around in setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY). My guess is that controls it.

Comment: u can see in code, i have already set data store factory for GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow

Comment: FileDataStoreFactory is probably saving the authentication some place. Once you have authenticated once its probably saved on your hard drive.   You need to figure out how to tell it that its a different user or use a different datastore.  https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/util/store/FileDataStoreFactory

Comment: ok thank you sir. do you any idea on those thing?

Comment: Yes my ideas would be the points I just gave you.   Either tell filedatastore its a different user or change to another type of datastore.

Comment: you're confusing Authorize with Authenticate. They're two different things

Answer (score 1):

By design the client library stores authorization information, so that the user isn't prompted every time they run your application. The client library persists authorization information to the `DataStore` instance you provide, in your case a `FileDataStore` which stores files in a particular directory.

Multiple users can share the same data store, but you need to pass a unique user identifier when performing authorization. For installed applications this is done in [`AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/extensions/java6/auth/oauth2/AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp#authorize(java.lang.String)), and for web applications it's done by overriding [`AbstractAuthorizationCodeServlet.getUserId`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/extensions/servlet/auth/oauth2/AbstractAuthorizationCodeServlet#getUserId(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)) and [`AbstractAuthorizationCodeCallbackServlet.getUserId`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/extensions/servlet/auth/oauth2/AbstractAuthorizationCodeCallbackServlet#getUserId(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)). See the Java client library's [OAuth2 guide](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2) for more information and examples.